# How to substract a day to a date field in Datastudio

Tags: looker-studio

I need to subtract a day from a date field in Datastudio. My date has the `DDMMYYYY` format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can now be achieved using the [`DATETIME_SUB`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9699809) function (which was introduced in the [17 Sep 2020 update to Dates and Times](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6311467#sep-17-2020)):

### 1) `Date - 1`

Where the field is represented by `Date`, the following [Calculated Field](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685) does the trick (subtracting a Day):

```
DATETIME_SUB(Date, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

### 2) Type (`Date - 1`)

```
Date
```

[Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/b3dd9d03-3de8-416c-b3a7-3d5e73f0ec72) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

DATETIME_SUB can also become more dynamic adding **another field or parameter** as its second parameter. BUT you have to CAST it as an int64_expression. Example:

```
DATETIME_SUB(Date_Field, INTERVAL CAST(Numeric_Field AS INT64) DAY)
```